# The maximum of minimum angle in multi-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: geometry, optimization

I'm interested in upper bounds of the following value:
\begin{align}
\max_{{\bf x}_1,\ldots,{\bf x}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{{\bf 0}\}} \min_{i\neq j} \frac{\langle{\bf x}_i,{\bf x}_j\rangle}{|{\bf x}_i||{\bf x}_j|}.
\end{align}
I think that this max-min problem is related to multi-dimensional packing problem but I don't know what the exact keyword is. Please recommend some keywords or links. Thanks.

Comment: Are you interpreting your problem like this? First take a finite list of non-zero vectors $x_1, \ldots, x_k$. Second, compute $\langle x_i, x_j \rangle / (|x_i||x_j|)$ for $i \neq j$. Third compute the minimum among those values. Fourth compute the maximum of the minimums among all possible finite list of non-zero vectors.

Comment: Yes, and I found that my problem with n=3 is equivalent to Tammes problem.